# Spring does not see repository during scan on app start

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

Have sandbox springboot app. Decided to try reactive approach, `postgres` is used as database, I added r2dbc to the project to make my repository reactive. Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Springboot2Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Springboot2Application.class, args);
   }
}

@Repository
public interface ToDoRepository extends 
            ReactiveCrudRepository<ToDo,String> {
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ToDoController {
    private final ToDoRepository repository;
    public ToDoController(ToDoRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/to-do", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, 
            MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Flux<ToDo>> getToDos(@RequestHeader 
                                          HttpHeaders headers){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(repository.findAll());
    }
}

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "todo")
public class ToDo {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String description;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp created;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp modified;
    private boolean completed;
}
```

r2dbc config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = 
   "com.springboot2.repository")
public class R2DBCConfig extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return ConnectionFactories.get(
            ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
                    .option(DRIVER, "postgresql")
                    .option(HOST, "localhost")
                    .option(PORT, 5432)
                    .option(USER, "admin")
                    .option(PASSWORD, "admin")
                    .option(DATABASE, "springdb")
                    .build());
   }
 }
```

On application start I'm getting:

Description:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.springboot2.controller.ToDoController required a bean of type 'com.springboot2.repository.ToDoRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.springboot2.repository.ToDoRepository' in your configuration.
```

I tried to add `@ComponentsScan`, tried to move `ToDoRepository` to the root near `Springboot2Application`, I dont understand why Spring doesn't see repository interface

pom.file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
<!--        <spring-shell.version>2.1.0</spring-shell.version>-->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--        DB,ORM, and plugins-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        Reactive libs-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess the reason is that you have added r2dbc driver to your project, but haven't added `spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc`

So, consider this dependency in your `pom.xml` file (this is the latest version at the time of writing this answer) :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

1. Also you can try to use `@EnableR2dbcRepositories` and specify the package with your repository.
2. One more possible way to solve this is to extend your repository from `R2dbcRepository`, instead of `ReactiveCrudRepository`
   This may help when you have multiple spring data reactive modules (r2dbc and something else) being used in the same project. Since `ReactiveCrudRepository` is a generic interface Spring does not know how to properly configure these beans.

Comment: unfortunately this didnt solve the problem..I added pom code to question

Comment: Also mvn clean install didn't help? Maybe try to add annotation @EnableR2dbcRepositories, try to specify the package where your repository located

Comment: updated r2dbc config with this annotation(updated code in question). maven clean install provided surefire report with error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.springboot2.repository.ToDoRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Also,  I can see spring-boot-starter-web dependency along with webflux in your pom.xml. In this case should be regular mvc autoconfigured, and maybe this is the reason why spring is not aware of reactive repositories.. Maybe try to remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency. And also remove spring-boot-starter-data-rest

Comment: And one more option: try to extend your repository from R2dbcRepository, instead of ReactiveCrudRepository

Comment: removed indicated dependencies and used r2dbc repo. so finally it works. but as I see problem was in interface - Spring could not find ReactiveCrudRepo, but easily found R2DBCRepo. This is strange, because guides from google indecate ReactiveCrudRepo..

Comment: right, the only reason I know is when you have multiple spring data reactive modules (r2dbc and something else) being used in the same project. Since ReactiveCrudRepository is a generic interface Spring does not know how to properly configure these beans. But I don't see any others reactive data modules in your project.

Comment: Also, updated my answer with possible solutions